# Storing the GML application schema in postgres

Tags: postgresql, gml

I have to store the application schema for a GML file which is in Xsd format in PostgreSQL table.

I want to use the ISO standards for that.

From what I have searched I think [ISO 19109](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=39891) has to be used.

Can anyone suggest some thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From What I have found I think we can simply parse the xsd and find the column names.Since the column names are in any case going to be in string format.We only need to store that as varchar in the postgres table.